# Assembler 86x. Перевод из восьмеричной системы счисления в двоичную напрямую

Tags: ассемблер

Нужно написать программу на assembler 86х, которая позволит переводить из восьмеричной системы счисления в двоичную без перевода в десятичную. 
Вопрос состоит в том, как именно это сделать, в какие ячейки что заносится и т.п.

Comment: Все чиселки и так в двоичной системе. Непонятно что и куда вы хотите перевести

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас на входе последовательность чисел от 0 до 8, тогда берем младший разряд и умножаем на 8^0, затем берем следующий и умножаем на 8^1 и прибавляем к предыдущему и т. д., как в школе учили.

Comment: Пользователь пишет натуральное число в восьмеричной системе счисления, программа принимает его и выдает его же, но в двоичной системе счисления

Answer (score 0):

начните с хвалы небесам - 2 и 8 системы связаны степенной зависимостью.
почитайте про алгоритм группировки.
если вкратце: 
1. каждый разряд в 8 системе = 3разряда в двоичной системе
2. в соответствии с небольшой табличкой сопоставляете каждый разряд и получаете двоичное представление (либо математически переводите. тут на вкус и цвет)
3. повторяете для остальных разрядов.

пример:

```
175 (8):
1(8) = 001(2)
7(8) = 111(2)
5(8) = 101(2)
Собираем в кучу:
175(8)= 001 111 101(2)
```

Это касаемо алгоритма.
По реализации - если на входе число в "текстовом" виде - сопоставляете в табличке символ. Если число - выделяете разряды с помощью shr и битовой маски and